# C# Using objects in other classes and displaying them *REVISED

Tags: c#, object, methods

I am having trouble display the object's properties and transferring them between classes. I am also having trouble getting the error message from the set methods. It seems I can enter anything without getting an error. I know the problem might have something in the object because I am just getting blank variable names when I try to display it.

```
    namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            double strength = 0;
            double dexterity = 0;
            double hitPoints = 0;
            double armor = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("--WELCOME TO THE BATTLE--\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the statistics for warrior one.");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Strength: ");
                strength = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Dexterity: ");
                dexterity = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Hit Points: ");
                hitPoints = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Armor: ");
                armor = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Warrior warriorOne = new Warrior(name, strength, dexterity, hitPoints, armor);

                Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the statistics for warrior two.");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Strength: ");
                strength = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Dexterity: ");
                dexterity = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Hit Points: ");
                hitPoints = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Armor: ");
                armor = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Warrior warriorTwo = new Warrior(name, strength, dexterity, hitPoints, armor);

            Console.WriteLine("\nWarriors:\n" + warriorOne.Name + "--" + "Strength " + warriorOne.Strength + ", Dexterity " + warriorOne.Dexterity + ", HitPoints " + warriorOne.HitPoints + ", Armor " + warriorOne.Armor);
            Console.WriteLine("\nWarriors:\n" + warriorTwo.Name + "--" + "Strength " + warriorTwo.Strength + ", Dexterity " + warriorTwo.Dexterity + ", HitPoints " + warriorTwo.HitPoints + ", Armor " + warriorTwo.Armor);

            Battlefield.Battle(warriorOne, warriorTwo);
        }
    }
    class Warrior
    {
        private double strength;
        private double dexterity;
        private double hitPoints;
        private double armor;

        public Warrior(string name, double strength, double dexterity, double hitPoints, double armor)
        {
            name = Name;
            this.strength = Strength;
            this.dexterity = Dexterity;
            this.hitPoints = HitPoints;
            this.armor = Armor;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Strength
        {
            get
            {
                return strength;
            }
            set
            {
                while (value < 10 & value > 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Strength has a range of 10-20. Please re-enter: ");
                    value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                strength = value;
            }
        }
        public double Dexterity
        {
            get
            {
                return dexterity;
            }
            set
            {
                while (value < 10 & value > 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dexterity has a range of 10-20. Please re-enter: ");
                    value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                dexterity = value;
            }
        }
        public double HitPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return hitPoints;
            }
            set
            {
                while (value < 10 & value > 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hit points have a range of 10-20. Please re-enter: ");
                    value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                hitPoints = value;
            }
        }
        public double Armor
        {
            get
            {
                return armor;
            }
            set
            {
                while (value < 0 & value > 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Armor has a range of 0-5. Please re-enter: ");
                    value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                armor = value;
            }
        }
    }
    class Battlefield
    {
        public static void Battle(Warrior warriorOne, Warrior warriorTwo)
        { Console.WriteLine(warriorOne.Name); }
}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your question down to a something more simple, with a short code example that illustrates the problem (not a link to source code). Posting your whole assignment and source code may be a little too much for most people to read.

Comment: What is your problem

Comment: I'm not going to read your question in full, but I skimmed it and didn't see a question. If you are having a problem, create a [mcve] (emphasis on "minimum", but it must also be enough to reproduce the problem), provide a _short_ description of what that example code should do, and provide a detailed explanation of what's going wrong. I note that you said you're having errors - you should include the full compile error text / runtime exception and stack trace.

Comment: My advice would be to ignore the assignment and create a separate project just to explore how to do whatever it is you're trying to do in the simplest way possible.Learning how to copy properties between objects, or read properties of another object, or whatever it is you're specifically having problems with can be solved much more simply if you use a simple example than trying to work it out alongside all that application logic. It would also give you a nice simple example to post here if you still have problems figuring it out.

Comment: I have updated the post to a more condensed version. Sorry about that, I wasn't really thinking.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is with your `Warrior` class, in the constructor where you try to set the `Name` property. You have this (I've only included the relevant bits):

```
public Warrior(string name)
{
    name = Name;
}

public string Name { get; set; }
```

Notice that you're **NOT** setting the `Name` property here. You are setting the argument `name` to whatever the `Name` property is (which is probably `null`).

To fix this, just switch the order around the assignment:

```
public Warrior(string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
```

You might want to check all your other properties as well (it looks like this was a common mistake, where you have the property you're trying to set on the *right* side of the `=` instead of the *left*).

Remember you should almost always assign to the public accessor (the capitalized one), so your `set` code runs. Try not to modify the private backing field except from the property `set` method.